# Magento Different Transactional Emails Per Store View

Tags: magento

This is a broad question I know, which is:

Can you send different transactional email templates for different stiore views in Magento?

For example if we had a store view that was styled in yellow, the email templates would be nice if they could also be yellow, then switch views for green (or for different languages) etc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually I've just worked this out and it's completely obvious....

Create a new email template in System > Transactional emails then assign this new template at store view level in System > Configuration > Sales Emails and for example for "New Order Confirmation Template"

I really do hope that this helps someone else as it's not so obvious to begin with!